# Web.config configuration for EF Migrations

Tags: web-config, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I am implementing Code-First Migrations on my project and want to not have to use Add-Migration and Update-Database all the time in the Package Manager Console.  I'd like for the updates to the database to happen automatically.

For this reason I updated my web.config file to do this.  I deleted my database, but for some reason when I fire up the application, it does not create the database.  Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my web.config

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <contexts>
      <context type="AuctionService.DataAccess.AuctionContext, AuctionService.DataAccess">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[AuctionService.DataAccess.AuctionContext, AuctionService.DataAccess], [AuctionService.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration, AuctionService.DataAccess]], EntityFramework">
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
```

**EDIT**

My code is in a WCF service and when I debugged this service I got this

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Unable to update database to match the current model
>   because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled.
>   Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or
>   enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ensuring you have set the [AutomaticMigrationsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.automaticmigrationsenabled%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) property to `true` in the constructor of your `AuctionService.DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration` class.

Once that is going, you may also get an exception if there's potential data loss; you can ignore this by setting the [AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration.automaticmigrationdatalossallowed%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) property to `true`.

For example:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<AuctionContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        // AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // You may want this also, but be careful.
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you can set this in the .config file (can't find documentation on this).

I believe that when you initially set up migrations, you can get the generated Configuration class to have that property set for you by running the command `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations`

Comment: Do you happen to know if it's possible to set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true in the web.config (via a transform). If I put it in my code, I'll be forever paranoid that it'll get run against a production system!

Comment: @IainGalloway, you could of course always create a custom appSetting that is read in the Configuration method. I chose to set the value with conditional compilation: `#if DEBUG
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
#else`